# Write protect expansion ROM area

Tags: bios, real-mode

As per PCIe FW spec 3.0, BIOS will write protect the expansion ROM region once init vector is completed, but for a BIOS which has no UEFI support and running in 16 bit real mode how does it ensure write protection ?